# Write three Scheme procedures to simulate these three gates: AND, OR and XOR

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

So far I have assumed that the last two should be:

```
(define or-gate
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (= a 1)
        1
        (if (= b 1)
            1
            0))))

(define xor-gate
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (= a b)
        0
        1)))
```

...but the AND one is puzzling. How can I implement it?

Comment: I wanted to show you code how to enter a node in an ordered list but you deleted your qestiom. If you still need a solution you may ask your question in English in my personal forum at http://cpp.forum24.ru/ in the first section of the forum (For beginners) and I will answer.:)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple if we remember that `=` can accept more than two parameters:

```
(define and-gate
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (= a b 1)
        1
        0)))
```

In words: the `and` logical connector is `true` if and only if both of its arguments are `true`, for all other arguments it's `false`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the truth table for `and`?  Actually if you have a truth table for any of `and` or `or` or `xor` then the algorithm is identical.

Let's make a function that accepts a truth table and returns a function that computes the gate logic

```
(define (gate-logic-for-truth-table table)
  (lambda (a b)
    (vector-ref (vector-ref table b) a)))
```

Now, with the truth table for `and` we produce the `and-gate` function:

```
(define and-gate (gate-logic-for-truth-table
                  '#(#(0 0)
                     #(0 1))))
```

And a mini-test:

```
> (and-gate 0 0)
0
> (and-gate 0 1)
0
> (and-gate 1 0)
0
> (and-gate 1 1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the parameters are either `1` or `0`:

For `or`, you don't need to look at `b` if `a` is `1` - the result is `1`. Otherwise the result is `b`.
For `and`, you don't need to look at `b` if `a` is `0` - the result is `0`. Otherwise the result is `b`.

If you want to make it as similar to `or-gate` as possible, you can replace the `1`s with `0`s in  the outer conditional:

```
(define and-gate
    (lambda (a b)
        (if (= a 0)
            0
            (if (= b 1)
                1
                0))))
```

or, if you want to stick to comparisons with `1`, you can rearrange the branches:

```
(define and-gate
    (lambda (a b)
        (if (= a 1)
            (if (= b 1)
                1
                0)
             0)))
```

It's possible to shorten the code:

```
(define and-gate
    (lambda (a b)
        (if (= a 1)
            b
            0)))
```

and

```
(define or-gate
    (lambda (a b)
        (if (= a 1)
            1
            b)))
```

but whether this is more readable is pretty individual.

Answer (score 1):

If we're going to work with gates, we probably ought to start by defining a method for constructing them. I mean we are going to have to construct three gates.

```
#lang racket

;; Gate Constructor
(define (make-gate predicate)
  (lambda (A B)
    (predicate A B)))
```

Then we can define the gates at a high level using wishful thinking:

```
(define and-gate
  (make-gate and-predicate))

(define or-gate
  (make-gate or-predicate))

(define xor-gate
  (make-gate xor-predicate))
```

Then we can arbitrarily define the internal gate logic however we fancy:

```
(define (and-predicate A B)
  (let ([a (if A 1 0)]
        [b (if B 1 0)])
    (= 2 (+ a b))))

(define (or-predicate A B)
  (let ([a (if A 1 0)]
        [b (if B 1 0)])
    (< 0 (+ a b))))

(define (xor-predicate A B)
  (let ([a (if A 1 0)]
        [b (if B 1 0)])
    (= 1 (+ a b))))
```

Then we do the real work of testing...ok, maybe we actually should have started by writing the tests.

```
(module+ test
  (require rackunit
       rackunit/text-ui)

  (define (make-test-harness test-function)
    (define (test-harness ins outs)
      (if (or (null? ins)
              (null? outs))
      'test-complete
      (begin
        (test-function (first ins)
                       (first outs))
        (test-harness (rest ins)
                      (rest outs)))))
    test-harness))

  (define gate-inputs
    '((#f #f)
      (#t #f)
      (#f #t)
      (#t #t)))

  (define and-truth-table
    '(#f #f #f #t))

  (define or-truth-table
    '(#f #t #t #t))

  (define xor-truth-table
    '(#f #t #t #f))


  (define (make-gate-test gate name)
    (lambda (input correct)
      (define A (first input))
      (define B (second input))
      (test-equal? name
                   (gate A B)
                   correct)))

  (define and-gate-test
    (make-gate-test and-gate "AND Gate Test"))
  (define or-gate-test
    (make-gate-test or-gate "OR Gate Test"))
  (define xor-gate-test
    (make-gate-test xor-gate "XOR Gate Test"))

  (define (and-tests)
    (define tests
      (make-test-harness and-gate-test))
    (tests gate-inputs and-truth-table))

  (define (or-tests)
    (define tests
      (make-test-harness or-gate-test))
    (tests gate-inputs or-truth-table))

  (define (xor-tests)
    (define tests
      (make-test-harness xor-gate-test))
    (tests gate-inputs xor-truth-table))

  (define-test-suite
    all-gate-tests
    (and-tests)
    (or-tests)
    (xor-tests))

  (run-tests all-gate-tests))
```

#### Run the Tests

```
racket@29761897.rkt> ,enter "/home/ben/StackOverflow/29761897.rkt"
12 success(es) 0 failure(s) 0 error(s) 12 test(s) run
0
```

Since all the tests pass, we can now turn in our homework [as always subject to academic policy].

#### Notes

Using truth values `#f` and `#t` provides cleaner hooks into Racket's testing tools. It also allows writing predicates directly rather than serializing and deserializing `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple definition where the truth table is clear:

```
(define (and-gate a b)
  (cond
    [(and (= a 0) (= b 0))  0]
    [(and (= a 0) (= b 1))  0]
    [(and (= a 1) (= b 0))  0]
    [(and (= a 1) (= b 1))  1]))
```

If we note that only one clause has 1 as a result and all others give 0,
we can write:

```
(define (and-gate a b)
  (cond
    [(and (= a 1) (= b 1))  1]
    [else                   0]))
```